# Importing csv file to R - factors read as characters

Tags: r, csv, import, character, logical-operators

New to R. When importing a csv file columns are being read as characters when they are in fact - or should be - factors. All three columns in question have only two levels (yes/no and male/female).

My attempt:
In the Import Text Data dialog box I change the the columns to factor by inserting a comma separated list of factors.

```
> LungCapDataCSVnew <- read_csv("~/file.csv", 
  col_types = cols(Caesarean = col_factor(levels = c("no", 
  "yes")), Gender = col_factor(levels = c("male", 
  "female")), Smoke = col_factor(levels = c("no", 
  "yes"))))

> View(file)

> class(Gender)
[1] "character"

> class(Smoke)
[1] "character"
```

As it shows, 'Gender' and 'Smoke' columns read as characters when they should be factors.

How to solve this?

Comment: maybe just use `read.csv`.

Comment: I'm confused that you are referring to columns without the data frame. Maybe you have an old attached data frame in your workspace? What does `class(LungCapDataCSVnew$Smoke)` show? What about `str(LungCapDataCSVnew)`?

Comment: could you provide a sample of your data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use can change character into factor

```
LungCapDataCSVnew$Smoke<-as.factor(LungCapDataCSVnew$Smoke)
LungCapDataCSVnew$Gender<-as.factor(LungCapDataCSVnew$Gender)
```

New to R .
Suggesting website- http://cran.r-project.org/manuals.html

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's strange that simply `read.csv()` without any extra arguments doesn't automatically read in your characters as factors.

After importing the file with `file <- read.csv("~/file.csv")`  you can try

```
i <- sapply(file, is.character)
file[i] <- lapply(file[i], as.factor)
```

To convert all character columns into factors

Answer (score -2):

As I have just discovered:
read.csv seems to detect factors and levels
read_csv does not, it just assigns the column heading as a character.